# Creating a community wiki joining multiple useful answers for different systems

Tags: support, community-wiki

I recently came across a question ([How to change image size Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown)) that has multiple useful answers, where many of the answers only work on specific systems (in this case, different implementations of Markdown). I would like to create a community wiki under this question that contains valid answers with headings for each popular Markdown implementation, but I'm not sure if this is overkill and I also don't want to take rep away from the existing answer posters.

Should I create a new community wiki answer that joins all the useful answers into one (while crediting OPs), request that the current accepted answer be turned into a community wiki and then edit it, or leave the answers alone? I want to make it easier for people to skim answers depending on their Markdown implementation, while making an ethical choice about who gets credit/rep. I would also likely be copying existing answers into a community wiki post, and I'm not sure if that is a good idea as I'm new to community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like overkill to worry about Community Wiki here.

I think your intended use of Community Wiki fits with [the actual intention of the feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), but I also think that the feature has flaws that have been discussed on site Metas and Meta Stack Exchange. Not to mention that there are newer and better tools on Stack Overflow (like Documentation). On other sites, that don't have Documentation and where a topic is much too big for a tag wiki entry, then I think you can probably get away with a Community Wiki post.

The biggest problem with your idea is ensuring clean attribution of other people's work. Even though you are posting it on Stack Overflow, my understanding is that you are creating a new work and need to abide by the CC-BY-SA rules for attributing each author of an existing post that you put into it. That could get pretty verbose and make a post harder to read.

It's OK to have multiple answers. I would suspect on most sites, there are multiple correct answers to many (if not all) questions, plus different people's experiences may offer slightly different perspectives. The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) addresses this well - the good answers are voted up (and it's implied that the bad/wrong/incomplete answers are voted down) and the accepted answer does not indicate the best or right answer, but the one that helped the asker.

In this specific instance, I'd say that the question is too broad. The question doesn't mention a specific Markdown implementation, and many of the answers are unique to a particular implementation - some don't even say which implementation(s) they are valid in. Given the tools we have now, this may be better suited to [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) (which has [a Markdown topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/markdown/topics)).

If there was a question like this on Programmers, I'd probably use the moderator lock to create a single Community Wiki answer. The question is not one I would want deleted (it's averaging almost 45k views per year and is still receiving attention), but isn't a good example of a question I want to see (it doesn't specify enough about the environment and is attracting a larger number of answers). I'm not sure if this is a viable solution on Stack Overflow, though, due to size and volume.